# Model training using Azure Container Instance with GPU much slower than local test with same container

Tags: azure, yolo, darknet, azure-container-instances, nvidia-docker

I am trying to train a Yolo computer vision model using a container I built which includes an installation of Darknet. The container is using the Nvidia supplied base image: nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04

Using Nvidia-Docker on my local machine with a gtx 1080 ti, training runs very fast, however that same container running as an Azure Container Instance with a  P100 gpu trains very slowly. It's almost as if it's not utilizing the gpu. I also noticed that the "nvidia-smi" command does not work in the container running in Azure, but it does work when I ssh into the container running locally on my machine.

Here is the Dockerfile I am using

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
LABEL maintainer="alex.c.schultz@gmail.com" \
      description="Pre-Configured Darknet Machine Learning Environment" \
      version=1.0

# Container Dependency Setup
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN apt-get install dos2unix -y
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install libopencv-dev -y

# setup virtual environment
WORKDIR /
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv venv
WORKDIR venv
RUN mkdir notebooks
RUN mkdir data
RUN mkdir output


# Install Darknet
WORKDIR /venv
RUN git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
RUN sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/g' darknet/Makefile
RUN sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/g' darknet/Makefile
WORKDIR /venv/darknet
RUN make

# Install common pip packages
WORKDIR /venv
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Setup Environment
EXPOSE 8888
VOLUME ["/venv/notebooks", "/venv/data", "/venv/output"]
CMD . /venv/bin/activate && jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root
```

The requirements.txt file is as shown below:

```
jupyter
matplotlib
numpy
opencv-python
scipy
pandas
sklearn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my training data was on an Azure File Share volume and the network latency was causing the training to be slow. I copied the data from the share into my container and then pointed the training to it and everything ran much faster.

Comment: I am also experiencing very slow training on Azure. Could you provide the detail on how you copied the data into the container? Thanks